# Scala reflection to cast using return type of method at runtime

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I am using reflection in scala and i want to generalize the code to cast object to return type of another method which is identified at runtime using reflection

I have tried to get return type of method using reflection but not able to use this in asInstance[] cast operation.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier
object Test5 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val runtimeClass = Class.forName("ConvertToUpper")
    invokeRuntimeMethod(runtimeClass, "toUpper")
  }

  def invokeRuntimeMethod(runtimeClass: Class[_], methodName: String): Unit = {
    val runtimeMethod = runtimeClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName)
    var runtimeClsConstructor: java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_] = null
    if (!Modifier.isStatic(runtimeMethod.getModifiers)) {
      runtimeClsConstructor = runtimeClass.getDeclaredConstructor()
      runtimeClsConstructor.setAccessible(true)
    }
    println("Return Type =>" + runtimeMethod.getReturnType)
    println("Generic Return Type => " + runtimeMethod.getGenericReturnType)

    runtimeMethod.setAccessible(true)
    val runtimeObj = if (runtimeClsConstructor != null) runtimeClsConstructor.newInstance()
    else runtimeClsConstructor

    val runtimeFunction = runtimeMethod.invoke(runtimeObj).asInstanceOf[Function1[String, String]]
    println("output => " + runtimeFunction("test"))

  }
}
```

Here i want to generalize the function so that i don't need to write Function1. I am already getting return type i.e. Generic Return Type => scala.Function1.
How can i use this return type in asInstanceOf directly instead of hard coding Function1 like  runtimeMethod.invoke(runtimeObj).asInstanceOf[runtimeMethod.getGenericReturnType]

Comment: If the type comes from runtime, how would you use it? You either need that information coming from another way at compile time. Our you will end up with something like `Any => Any`. - May I ask, what is your use case? How do you want it to be generic? And, why did you needed reflection in a first place?

Comment: My use case is to provide runtimeFunction type to spark method (spark.udf.register) , So that udf function can be called with required number of arguments like spark.udf.register("toUpper",runtimeFunction)

Comment: But then, will the name of the method came in runtime? Then, even if you could extract the arguments and return type dynamically, you will need to propagate all that information to where the UDF is being used, and all those values should come from runtime too? Or, if you use this at compile time, you need would need to provide the type information statically. - Anyways, for the first case, it seems you will br mainly programming in runtime, and for the second it seems reflection is actually not needed at all. - I would recommend you to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: Runtime reflection is generally a code smell/design issue symptom

Comment: This may be an X-Y-problem (meaning there may be another way to achieve what you need to do without reflection -- which is usually avoided in Scalaland). What do you really need to do?

Answer (score 0):

> I am already getting return type i.e. Generic Return Type => scala.Function1.

You know this at runtime.

> How can i use this return type in asInstanceOf directly instead of hard coding Function1

To do this you should know at compile time that it's `Function1`.

So the question is if you know at compile time that the method `ConvertToUpper#toUpper` returns `Function1` or this can be everything.

If so then you can try to cast  to `Function1[Any, Any]` (if it's not known at compile time that arguments are `String`s)

```
val runtimeFunction = runtimeMethod.invoke(runtimeObj).asInstanceOf[Function1[Any, Any]]
```

If not then you can't know that you can call `apply` in `runtimeFunction("test")` (aka `runtimeFunction.apply("test")`).

---

If the only problem is that a function can be `Function1`, `Function2`... then you should match

```
runtimeMethod.invoke(runtimeObj) match { 
  case _ : Function1[_, _] => ???
  case _ : Function2[_, _, _] => ???
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Below is the more details about my use case:

1) First user will prepare udf like he creates ConvertToUpper class having toUpper method.
2) Now user pass above udf jar in spark class path and provide fully qualified method name like ConvertToUpper.toUpper for spark udf register.
3) Along with above he will provide query like select toUpper(col1) from test;

Here I want spark udf register should be generic, I do not want put checks like if user defined function is of type Function1 or Function2 or Function3.

Comment: @HemendraYadav if the only problem is that a function can be `Function1`, `Function2`... then you should match `runtimeMethod.invoke(runtimeObj) match {
      case _ : Function1[_, _] => ???;
      case _ : Function2[_, _, _] => ???; ...
    }`

Comment: Here there 22 Function{1...22} and also there are 22 UDF{1....22} and other types as well. I do not want to put check for each and every one.

Comment: @HemendraYadav that's the reason why people generate code in scala https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/project/Boilerplate.scala#L158-L229 https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/project/GenerateFunctionConverters.scala